# How to call a function in an another view controller in Xamarin.ios?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, event-handling

I have a controller called `LeftViewController` representing a sidemenu for my main  controller `ViewController`. I want when I click a button in the sidemenu to call a function in the main ViewController and change the title of my button. I tried to define a class `refresh_all`  in `ViewController.cs` to be responsible of updating titles of my button , and from there I would define an object from `ViewController` to call a function from it.

```
 public  class refresh_all{


        ViewController v1 = new ViewController();

        public void refresh_components()
        {


            v1.refresh_ac(); //

        }

    }
```

Function in `ViewController` class :

```
 public void refresh_ac()
        {
            s2.SetTitle(CommonClass.value.ToString(), UIControlState.Normal);//s2 is my button name
        }
```

I defined an object from `refresh_all` class in `LeftViewController` controller as follow :

```
    partial void Conbtn_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
        {

            refresh_all r1 = new refresh_all();

            r1.refresh_components();

        }
```

I am getting an error on `s2.SetTitle(CommonClass.value.ToString(), UIControlState.Normal);`
saying `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check s2 button object and CommonClass object. "CommonClass.value" Here CommonClass should be an instance/object of the class to call the properties.

Send the ViewController object in LeftViewController and then send to the refresh_all class.

Comment: CommonClass is a static class with static attributes

Comment: Can you please provide full stack trace of exception?

Comment: it's saying that s2 is (null) .

Comment: are the controls in the ViewController using another object?

Comment: that's why you are getting an exception. You will have to initialize s2 button.

Comment: Are you initializing s2 button in ViewController constructer?

Comment: how do I initialize it from the constructor

Comment: Please initialize s2 in constructor. You can create your UIButton s2 = new UIButton() in constructor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224209/discussion-between-jai-and-taher-el-hares).

Answer (score 0):

### Events

I managed to get the event approch working. My information was based on the following links:

- [PresentViewController and pass data back](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22543/presentviewcontroller-and-pass-data-back)
- [Communicate Between Master and Detail Controllers](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/split_view/communicate_between_master_and_detail_controllers/)
- [A better UITableViewSource in Xamarin iOS](http://www.mourfield.com/2013/09/better-uitableviewsource-xamarin-ios/)
- [Event Handling UITableViewSource for iOS with Monotouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715905/event-handling-uitableviewsource-for-ios-with-monotouch)

In my `UITableViewController` (view controller B) I added the following:

```
// class variable  
public event EventHandler<BLevelSelectedEventArgs> BLevelSelected;

// event handler
public class BLevelSelectedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public BLevelItem bLevel { get; set; }

    public BLevelSelectedEventArgs(BLevelItem bLevel) : base()
    { 
        this.bLevel = bLevel;
    }
}
```

Here the event as well as the custom event handler is defined. You can define the properties you want to transport the data with the event e.g. string. Here a custom `BLevelItem` is used. The name of the event handler and the name of the event should be changed for your application. In this `UITableViewController` class I also have the `UITableViewSource` defined.

```
public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true); // iOS convention is to remove the highlight

    if (this.controller.BLevelSelected != null) {
        this.controller.BLevelSelected (this, new BLevelSelectedEventArgs (controller.bLevelList[indexPath.Row]));
    }

}
```

Here the event is raised and the parameter are passed with the event. Now only one listener is missing which reacts on the event. This goes on view controller A:

```
bLevelController.BLevelSelected += (object sender, BLevelController.BLevelSelectedEventArgs e) => {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.bLevel.bLevelName);
};
```

`bLevelController` is an instance of my view controller B. You can access the defined event as seen above, but you have to be aware that you use the class name (`BLevelController`) to access `BLevelSelectedEventArgs`.

It would be nice if one you could also add the other possibilities to pass the data between view controllers (Notification center, Protocol/Delegates, ...).

---

### Delegate

A kind of delegate method is used [Part 5 - Working with Tables in the iOS Designer](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/tables/part_5_-_creating_Tables_in_a_Storyboard/). You define a *Delegate* in your `UITableViewController`:

```
public MasterViewController Delegate {get;set;} // will be used to Save, Delete later
```

When you instantiate the *DetailViewController* in the *MasterViewController* you set the *Delegate* property. Example:

```
public override void PrepareForSegue (UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
{
    base.PrepareForSegue (segue, sender);

    var detailViewController = segue.DestinationViewController as DetailViewController;

    if (detailViewController != null) {
        detailViewController.Delegate = this;
    }
}
```

In the *DetailViewController* you can call any method from the *MasterViewController*:

```
public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
    tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true); // iOS convention is to remove the highlight
    if (this.controller.Delegate != null) {
        this.controller.Delegate.SetItems (this.controller.items[indexPath.Row]);
    }
}

// a method in MasterViewController
public void SetItems(string items){
    this.items = items;
    this.NavigationController.PopViewControllerAnimated (true);
    // do something here
}
```

This works because I pass the *DetailViewController* to the *DetailViewSource*:

```
// in ViewDidLoad of DetailViewController
this.TableView.Source = new DetailViewSource (this);

// in the constructor of DetailViewSource
private CostCentreController controller;

public CostCentreListSource (CostCentreController controller)
{
    this.controller = controller;
}
```

---

### NSNotificationCenter

My information are based on [xamarin/monotouch-samples](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/AppPrefs/AppDelegate.cs) and [Xamarin NSNotificatioCenter: How can I get the NSObject being passed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486010/xamarin-nsnotificatiocenter-how-can-i-get-the-nsobject-being-passed).

Simple example without data transfer:

```
// class level variable
NSObject observer;

// register as observer
public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear (animated);
    observer = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver ((NSString)UIDevice.OrientationDidChangeNotification, OrientationChanged);
}

// deregister as observer
public override void ViewDidDisappear (bool animated)
{
    base.ViewDidDisappear (animated);
    if (observer != null) { 
        NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver (observer);
        observer = null;
    }
}

// function which should do something when notification is received
public void OrientationChanged(NSNotification notification){
    Console.WriteLine ("test");
    // perhaps you can do the following as in the linked SO question: NSObject myObject = notification.Object;
}
```

Referenc [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25665884/10768653)